# Step/Impulse function setup confusion

Tags: laplace-transform

I have a final coming up next week (Tuesday) and a sample question for the test is the following.

I was wondering if I have properly set it up for solving with Laplace as I haven't encountered a question with two level changes before and it's confussed me.

First line is the question and the second line is my questionable setup.
[image]

My understanding is that I'm doing this...

level+(newLevel-oldLevel)U(t-PointOfChange)

Finding good examples of Step & Impulse online has proven to be a greater challenge than I thought it would be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by levels, but if apply the Laplace transform to the right hand side you just get $$\int_\pi^{2\pi} e^{-st}dt,$$ which can be evaluated explicitly, right?

Comment: It's a graph of 'something' over time.  That 'something' could be voltage level or switch on/off indication.  So the level could be 0mV/100mV or 0/1.

Comment: Do you mean $y''+y=f(t)$ since you gave two initial conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified two initial conditions, I will assume you meant to solve
$$y''+y=f(t)=\begin{cases}0, &0<t<\pi,\\ 1, &\pi<t<2\pi,\\ 0, &t>2\pi.\end{cases}$$

In preparation for Laplace transforming both sides of the equation, let's look at how to compute $\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}$. One way is directly from the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition):
 $$
\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} 1\cdot e^{-st}\,dt={1\over s}\left(e^{-\pi s}-e^{-2\pi s}\right).
$$
However, it sounds like you are curious about how to compute the transform after rewriting $f(t)$ as a combination of unit step functions. Here's how (and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/257581/52893) might help to see how to get this form):
\begin{align}
f(t)&=u(t-\pi)-u(t-2\pi)\\
\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}&=\mathscr{L}\{u(t-\pi)\}-\mathscr{L}\{u(t-2\pi)\}={e^{-\pi s}\over s}-{e^{-2\pi s}\over s},
\end{align}
which is of course the same result as the previous method.

Now we are ready. Laplace transforming both sides,
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\left\{y''+y\right\}&=\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}\\
s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+Y(s)&={1\over s}\left(e^{-\pi s}-e^{-2\pi s}\right)\\
Y(s)&={e^{-\pi s}-e^{-2\pi s}\over s(s^2+1)}\\
Y(s)&={e^{-\pi s}\over s}\cdot {1\over s^2+1}-{e^{-2\pi s}\over s}\cdot {1\over s^2+1}
\end{align}

In this form, the inverse transforms on the right-hand side are readily doable via the [Convolution Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems):

\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}&=\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left\{{e^{-\pi s}\over s}\cdot {1\over s^2+1}-{e^{-2\pi s}\over s}\cdot {1\over s^2+1}\right\}\\
y(t)&=u(t-\pi)*\sin t-u(t-2\pi)*\sin t\\
y(t)&=\int_0^t u(\tau-\pi)\sin(t-\tau)\,d\tau -\int_0^t u(\tau-2\pi)\sin(t-\tau)\,d\tau\\
y(t)&=(1+\cos t)u(t-\pi)-(1-\cos t)u(t-2\pi).
\end{align}

Here's a plot of the input $f(t)$ (red) and the system response $y(t)$ (blue):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope that helps.